# How to convert text value to number with truncating first or last character of text in protractor?

Tags: protractor

I want to get numeric value of column rate and percentage with $ and % removed from text.

I have tried replace but it is not working.

HTML code is as below:

```
<tbody _ngcontent_1="">
<tr class="class-1" _ngcontent_1="">
<td class="label" _ngcontent_1="">xyz</td>
<td class="rate" _ngcontent_1="">$5.00</td>
<td class="percentage" _ngcontent_1="">12.00%</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this i believe:

```
let convertToFloat = (textToConvert)=> {
    let cleared = textToConvert.replace("$", "").replace("%", "");
    return parseFloat(cleared)
}

let ratevalue = $('.rate').getText().then(convertToFloat)
let percentagevalue = $('.percentage').getText().then(convertToFloat)

expect(ratevalue).toEqual(5.00)
expect(percentagevalue).toEqual(12.00)
```

Don't forget about promises.